# SOLR query exclusions

Tags: coldfusion, solr

I'm having an issue with querying an index where a common search term also happens to be part of a company name interspersed throughout most of the documents.  How do I exclude the business name in results without effecting the ranking on a search that includes part of the business name?

example: Bobs Automotive Supply is the business name.

How can I include relevant results when someone searches automotive or supply without returning every document in the index?

I tried "-'Bobs Automotive Supply' +'search term'" but this seems to exclude any document with  Bobs Automotive Supply and isn't very effective on searching 'supply' or 'automotive'

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Second answer here, based on additional clarification from first answer.

A few options.

1. Add the business name as StopWords in the StopWordFilter. This will stop Solr from Indexing them at all. Searches that use them will only really search for those words that aren't in the business name.
2. Rely on the inherent scoring that Solr will apply due to Term frequency. It sounds like these terms will be in the index frequently. Queries for them will still return the documents, but if the user queries for other, less common terms, those will get a higher score.
3. Apply a low query boost (not quite negative, but less than other documents) to documents that contain the business name. This is covered in the Solr Relevancy FAQ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_do_I_give_a_negative_.28or_very_low.29_boost_to_documents_that_match_a_query.3F

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that the article is tied to the business name or derive this?  If so, you could create another field and then just exclude entities that match on the business name using a filter query.  Something like

```
q=search_term&fq=business_name:(NOT search_term)
```

It may be helpful to use subqueries for this or to just boost down rather than filter out results.

Comment: Custom fields aren't really an option since these are marketing materials that contain the name umpteen times over.  Can you you boost down a phrase without effecting the individual terms in the phrase?  If thats the case i could create an exclusions field.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Update to question make this irrelavent. Leaving it hear for posterity. :)

This is why Solr Documents have different fields.

In this case, it sounds like there is a "Footer" field that is separate from your "Body" field in your documents. When searches are performed, they would only done against the Body, which won't include data from the Footer. You could even have a third field which is the "OriginalContent" field, which contains the original copy for display purposes. You wouldn't search that, just store it for later.

The important part is to create the two separate fields in your schema and make sure that you index those field that you want to be able to search.

Comment: The problem is that the business name is interspersed throughout the document.  There doesn't seem to be an easy way to exclude it through custom fields.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect that. You only described it being in the Footer.